# d3 multiple line chart tooltip doesn't update correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a multiple line chart with update function, however, my tooltip doesn't update accordingly. I'm pretty new to D3, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

You can see the whole thing here: 
http://bl.ocks.org/jeremycflin/a5a7824a974d4b704fcf

Here's my code. 
CSS
    
    body { font: 12px Helvetica Neue;}

```
path { 
stroke: #;
stroke-width: ;
fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #e7eff1;
stroke-width: 1;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.graph-svg-component {
background-color:#e7eff1;
opacity:0.9;
}

.overlay {
fill: none;
pointer-events: all;
}

.focus circle {
fill: #990000;
}

.line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #7ea7ba;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-width: 2.5px;
 }

.line-hover {
 stroke: #cc6200;
 stroke-width:3;
  }

 .voronoi path {
 fill: none;
 pointer-events: all;
 }

 .grid .tick{
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:1.5px;
 stroke-opacity:0.9;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }

 .grid path{
 stroke-width:0;
 }

.lable{
font-size: 30;
}

.lable-hover{
font-size: 30;
}

.focus text{
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}
</style>
```

D3 code's here:

```
             var margin = {top: 60, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 60},
                width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse,
                bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.Year; }).left,
                formatValue = d3.format(",.2f");

            var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
            var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                .orient("bottom").ticks(7);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                .orient("left").ticks(10);


            var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); })
                .clipExtent([[-margin.left, -margin.top], [width + margin.right, height + margin.bottom]]);

            // var valueline1 = d3.svg.line()
            //     // .interpolate("basis") 
            //     .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
            //     .y(function(d) { return y(d.Fossil_Fuels); });

            var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis") 
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.Nuclear_Electric_Power); });

            // var valueline3 = d3.svg.line()
            //     // .interpolate("basis") 
            //     .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
            //     .y(function(d) { return y(d.test); });

            var valueline4 = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis") 
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.Coal); });

            var valueline5 = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis") 
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.Natural_Gas ); });

            var valueline6 = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis") 
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.Crude_Oil ); });

            var valueline7 = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis") 
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.Biofuels ); });

            var valueline8 = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis") 
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.Other_Renewable ); });

            var valueline9 = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis") 
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.Total_Energy_Production ); });


            var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .attr("class", "graph-svg-component")
                .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


            tmp = null;

            function make_x_axis() { return d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(5)
            }
            function make_y_axis() { return d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(10)
            }

            // Get the data
            d3.csv("texas_energy_production.csv", function(error, data) {

                var flatData = [];
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.Year = parseDate(d.Year);
                    // d.Fossil_Fuels = +d.Fossil_Fuels;
                    d.Nuclear_Electric_Power = +d.Nuclear_Electric_Power;
                    d.test = +d.test;
                    d.Coal = +d.Coal
                    d.Natural_Gas = +d.Natural_Gas;
                    d.Crude_Oil = +d.Crude_Oil;
                    d.Biofuels = +d.Biofuels;
                    d.Other_Renewable = +d.Other_Renewable;
                    // d.Total_Energy_Production = +d.Total_Energy_Production;


                    // flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Fossil_Fuels, key: "Fossil_Fuels"});
                    flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Nuclear_Electric_Power, key: "Nuclear_Electric_Power"});
                    // flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.test, key: "test"});
                    flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Coal, key: "Coal"});
                    flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Natural_Gas, key: "Natural_Gas"});
                    flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Crude_Oil, key: "Crude_Oil"});
                    flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Biofuels, key: "Biofuels"});
                    flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Other_Renewable, key: "Other_Renewable"});
                    // flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Total_Energy_Production, key: "Total_Energy_Production"});




                });

                // Scale the range of the data
                x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year; }));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max( d.Nuclear_Electric_Power,d.Natural_Gas,d.Crude_Oil,d.Biofuels,d.Other_Renewable); })]) 

                // Add the valueline path.
                // svg.append("path")       
                //  .attr("class", "line")
                //  .attr("d", valueline1(data));

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "grid")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(make_x_axis()
                        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                        .tickFormat("")
                    )
                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "grid")
                    .call(make_y_axis()
                        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                        .tickFormat("")
                    )




                // svg.append("path")      
                //     .attr("class", "line Fossil_Fuels") 
                //     .attr("d", valueline1(data));

                svg.append("path")      
                    .attr("class", "line Nuclear_Electric_Power")  
                    .attr("d", valueline2(data));


                // svg.append("path")      
                //     .attr("class", "line test")
                //     .attr("d", valueline3(data));

                svg.append("path")      
                    .attr("class", "line Coal")
                    .attr("d", valueline4(data));

                svg.append("path")      
                    .attr("class", "line Natural_Gas")
                    .attr("d", valueline5(data));

                svg.append("path")      
                    .attr("class", "line Crude_Oil")
                    .attr("d", valueline6(data));

                svg.append("path")      
                    .attr("class", "line Biofuels")
                    .attr("d", valueline7(data));

                 svg.append("path")      
                    .attr("class", "line Other_Renewable")
                    .attr("d", valueline8(data));

                 // svg.append("path")      
                 //    .attr("class", "line Total_Energy_Production")
                 //    .attr("d", valueline9(data));








                svg.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

                svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis);



                var focus = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "focus")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)");

                focus.append("circle")
                  .attr("r", 4);

                focus.append("text")
                  .attr("x", -9)
                  .attr("y",-15)
                  .attr("dy", ".35em");

                var voronoiGroup = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "voronoi");

                voronoiGroup.selectAll("path")
                  .data(voronoi(flatData))
                  .enter().append("path")
                  .attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; })
                  .datum(function(d) { return d.point; })
                  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                  .on("mouseout", mouseout);

                function mouseover(d) {
                  console.log(d);
                  d3.select("."+d.key).classed("line-hover", true);
                  focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.Year) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
                  focus.select("text")
                        .text( d.key+" "+d.value )
                        .style("font-size", "14")
                        .style("opacity", "0.75")
                        .style("font-weight","500");
                }

                function mouseout(d) {
                  d3.select("."+d.key).classed("line-hover", false);
                  focus.attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)");
                }




            });



             // ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
                function updateData() {

                // Get the data again
                d3.csv("data2.csv", function(error, data) {
                    var flatData = [];
                    data.forEach(function(d) {
                        d.Year = parseDate(d.Year);
                        d.Total_Energy_Production = +d.Total_Energy_Production;
                        flatData.push({Year: d.Year, value: d.Total_Energy_Production, key: "Total_Energy_Production"});
                    });

                    // Scale the range of the data again 
                    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year; }));
                    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Total_Energy_Production; })]);

                // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
                var change = d3.select("body").transition().ease("linear");



                // var change = d3.selectAll("body").transition()
                //          .ease("linear")
                //          .duration(1200)
                //          .attr("d", valueline9(data));

                // Make the changes
                    change.selectAll(".line")   // change the line
                        .duration(1200)
                        .attr("d", valueline9(data))
                        .attr("class", "line Total_Energy_Production");




                    // svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
                    //     .duration(750)
                    //     .call(xAxis);
                    change.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
                        .duration(750)
                        .call(yAxis);




                    // change.selectAll(".voronoi").remove();






                   //  d3.selectAll(".focus")
                         // .data(function (d) { return d.Total_Energy_Production })





                });
            }
```

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?  Your tooltip is not matching the displayed line data because you're not updating the `mouseover` function to match the new data.  It is still referencing `flatData`, and since it's triggered off a `g` element that is not getting removed on update, it still fires and displays the corresponding `flatData` values.

Comment: Thank you so much. So does that mean i should write another new mouseover and then point it to the new flatData ? Apologize in advance if it sounded basic....

Comment: I figured it out! thank you!